# How i can to get the attributes of min and max price from slider range

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, model-view-controller, razor

How i can get the min and max price from this Div

```
                                <div class="slider-range mb-15">
                                    <div class="range-price text-white">Price [30000 -  150000]$</div>
                                    <div class="slider-range-price ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" data-min="0" data-max="200000" data-unit="$" data-value-min="30000" data-value-max="150000" data-label-result="Price">
                                        <div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header ui-corner-all"></div>
                                        
                                        <span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0"></span>
                                        <span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

***Edit***

this div how it works

[image]

I want to add  the min and max price Price[x y] to parameters min = x , max = y
the values are changing into span tag

Comment: HI, please can you elaborate more and show your attempts .

Comment: Hi thank you for response , I edit the question and i add the interface of div , the values change into span plz click on gif to see big pic .

Comment: Hi, on change of range slider you need value of `data-min="0" data-max="200000"` ?

Comment: yes , but when i change  `data-min="0" data-max="200000"` or `data-value-min="0"`  `data-value-max="200000"` to `data-min="min" data-max="max"` or `data-value-min="min"` `data-value-max="max"` the slider range not working how i can get the selected range ?

Comment: did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577293/set-max-value-dynamically-to-the-slider) post ?